# Change color of to recycler view items from the on item click callback function in activity

Tags: android, callback, android-recyclerview

**Change RecyclerView Item color from activity.**

I have handled recycler view item click by implementing the adapter callback interface.I have also passed the adapterPosition to callback function in activity for my condition check.

**MyActivitiy class**

```
@Override
public void onSideAClicked(List<Faq> dataList, int itemPosition) {
    sideA_ID = dataList.get(itemPosition).getId();
    positionA = itemPosition + 1;
    sideAisClicked = true;
    if (checkIfMatched())
        // Here checkIfMatched() is true then set new color to recyclerview item at position itemPosition or if possible make the item non clickable
}
```

**MyAdapter class**

```
public class SideARecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SideARecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

SideAAdapterCallback callback;
private Context context;
private List<Faq> faqList;

public SideARecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Faq> faqList, SideAAdapterCallback sideAAdapterCallback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.faqList = faqList;
    this.callback = sideAAdapterCallback;
}
public interface SideAAdapterCallback {
    void onSideAClicked(List<Faq> dataList, int position);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_items, viewGroup,false);
    ViewHolder mh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.faq_position.setText((i + 1) + "");
    viewHolder.faq_question.setText(faqList.get(i).getQuestion());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != faqList ? faqList.size() : 0);
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView faq_position;
    private TextView faq_question;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.faq_position = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.faq_position);
        this.faq_question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.faq_question);

        this.itemView.setClickable(true);
        this.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onSideAClicked(faqList, position);
        }
    }

}
```

*// Here if checkIfMatched() returns true then set new color to recyclerview item 
 at position itemPosition or if possible make the item non clickable*

Answer (score 0):

For changing color of selected row define a variable in adapter `int selectedPosition;` in class level and in `onBindViewHolder()` method do:

```
if(selectedPosition == i){
   //Change row color
}
else{
   //Set default color
}
```

Edit:

If you want to compare two recycler view selected position in one activity, add this method in your adapters:

```
void setSelected (int position){
  this.selectedPosition = position;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

after getting `selectedPostition` in your activity with a callback and check your condition call `adapter.setSelected(position)`

Comment: I need to compare selectedPosition of two recycler views in activity so I am bound to change the color from my activity method sideAClicked() instead of changing from adapter's onBindViewHolder().